# Styling SearchView suggestions

Tags: android, searchview

I've implemented a SearchView in my appbar/toolbar and I am offering search suggestions to the user. My app is dark with white text but I would like to have a list of suggestions that is light with dark text...

I saw some posts explaining how to do this by "digging" into the view elements themselves, isn't there a better way to just indicate Android that this particular View should use the Light theme?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a light theme on your file `styles.xml` and refer at the property `android:theme` under the view you want to change, so all children will inherit the theme.

**Example**

```
<style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

---

Under your view properties

```
android:theme="@style/MyCustomTheme"
```

I hope I've helped

Comment: The problem is this View I am not explicitly creating on a XML, but it´s created automatically when clicking the menu button for search. Technically it´s specified by declaring an action view on the menu xml.